# Correct way of using variables from global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a simple global.asax file that runs some code at startup and stores a handle in a variable. I want to access that variable from my other files in the project. Here is my global.asax:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">

    static JustTesting justTesting;
    static public JustTesting JustTesting { get { return justTesting ; } }

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        //my code here
    }

    void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        //  Code that runs on application shutdown

    }

    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

    }
</script>
```

And when I want to use that variable...

```
ASP.global_asax.JustTesting
```

...which works, but I'm sure there must be a more elegant way of calling it instead of having to add `ASP.global_asax.` all the time.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You could use public static variables in public classes, but I'd really urge you not to.

Do these variables values change? What do they represent? Don't forget that all users will use the same set of variables.  If you really need application wide variables i would use the `Cache`. Or create a public class as wrapper for the `Cache` which returns the objects strongly typed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Application` object.

Reading:

```
var x = Application["x"];
```

Writing:

```
Application.Lock();
Application["x"] = "value";
Application.UnLock();
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf(v=vs.90).aspx

You can also create your own class, which should be thread safe.